# How to Add custom menu to Bottom App Bar?

Tags: android, material-design, android-bottomappbar

I am using new Material Bottom app bar in android. I have implemented it successfully but I don't know how to add custom menu items to the bar. Whenever I add the menu items they shows up as 3 dots only even if I provide the option android:showAsAction="always".

I want specific icons like the screenshot below.[image: Wanted result]
But instead I get result like this.
[image]

Here is the layout code.

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:fabCradleMargin="5dp"
    app:fabAlignmentMode="center"/>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar" />
```

And here is the java code.

```
BottomAppBar bottomAppBar = (BottomAppBar) findViewById(R.id.bottom_app_bar);
setSupportActionBar(bottomAppBar);

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Menu code.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_explore"
    android:icon="@drawable/explore"
    android:title="Explore"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
    android:icon="@drawable/profile"
    android:title="Profile"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After so much research I finally found the solution to the problem. Just by changing namespace of 'showAsAction' from 'android' to 'app' make things work.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_explore"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="Explore"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Answer (score 1):

use `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"`

I got it to work with the new Material Bottom App Bar to show icons.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource

Comment: I already tried that before yet again tried it and its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Popup Menu for that. Place an menu image and on click of image open the Popup Menu of android it is same like menu.

```
  PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, button);  
            //Inflating the Popup using xml file  
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());  

            //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener  
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {  
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {  
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                    return true;  
                }  
            });  

            popup.show();
```

You can follow below link:
https://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example

Comment: This is absolutely opposite of which I want to do. I want specific icons for my menu items not a pop up like in screenshot a uploaded. Read the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the fabCradleDiameter to 0db in the BottomAppBar like:
`app:fabCradleDiameter="0dp"`

Comment: Not sure if this answers the question asked. Can you post code and, if possible, screenshots as part of your answer?